# Handy File Processing / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm searching for quite some time now a handy Method or even better, a Gem, that would allow me to `CRUD` Files.

Specific needs are:

- Create a file from a `:text` string. (and control file type. e.g. `test.js`)
- Edit the File (Rewrite) if an update has occurred to `:text`
- Basically the whole `CRUD` Powerhouse.

Now, of course i know that there is no Magic Willie that will do this all by himself, i'm just looking for a right direction, from where i can start.

**Use Case:**

We have a `documents` controller with the variables:

```
:title
:body
:user_id
```

The `:body` (a simple text_area input) contains some `.js` code. How can i create a file (e.g `test.js`) based on `:body` which was entered by the User.

E.g. for simply creating the file => `File.open('text.js', 'w') { |file| file.write(@something.body) }`

### So far i'm here

```
def create

  @script = current_user.scripts.build(script_params)

  # Creating Folder (if it doesn't exist already)
  directory_name = "#{Rails.root}/public/userscripts/#{@script.user_id}"
  Dir.mkdir(directory_name) unless File.exists?(directory_name)

  # Write the file with model attribute :source
  File.open("public/userscripts/#{@script.user_id}/#{@script.name}.user.js", 'w') { |file|  file.write(@script.source) }



end
```

Comment: what if `test2.js` is created outside of your program? Should variable `test2` spring into existence? :)

Comment: Your specification is full of holes and I don't think such thing exists. You can always implement it yourself, though.

Comment: Let me Edit my Question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) will allow you to attach files and you can update them as well.

You can create a temporary file, assign it to the attachment attribute, then save the model.

```
    # create and write a file with the contents you want
    open "/tmp/tmpfile" do |f|
      model.attachment = f
      model.save!
    end
```

You can put this in a `before_save` filter to always update the file attachment.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file attachment
  before_save :update_attachment

  def update_attachment
    File.open("/tmp/tmpfile", 'w') { |file|  file.write(self.body) }
    open "/tmp/tmpfile" do |f|
      self.attachment = f
      self.attachment_content_type = "text/javascript"
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm working with paperclip.. The problem for me right now is that i don't really understand (still trying to learn) how i can create the file from the model attribute and CRUD it accordingly. I'll update my Question with what i've got so far.

Comment: I will have to run the generator for paperclip first right ? I mean rails g paperclip script attachment or `add_attachment :scripts, :attachment` in the CreateScripts migration.

Comment: Yes, see this [section](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start), and the Migrations section.